# Windows 10 - MS Access - VBA - pdflatex missing pdf output after compiling .tex file

Tags: errors, pdftex, miktex, compiling, windows

probably this is a Win problem, but I don't know where it could be solved. My scenario: I've created a MS Access db with forms, subs, functions and so on. I extract data from this db in order to produce .tex file and compile it automatically with a shell command "pdflatex C:\mypath\myfile.tex". Everything is fine, from the data extraction to the creation of the .tex file. When i launch the command in the shell (with the VBA code shell("pdflatex C:\mypath\myfile.tex") or shell("C:\mypath\compile.bat") the shell pops up, it starts compiling the .tex file and it arrives to the end of compiling process with no errors without producing the output pdf file. On the contrary if I open the cmd manually and I write the pdflatex command or I simply click on the compile.bat file (which simply contains the same pdflatex command), the pdf file is produced as desired. I cannot understand the reason the pdf can be obtained only by launching the command manually and not automatically with VBA. Could this be caused by any Win security setting? Thank you for the help.

Comment: No idea if it is related, but normally it is not a good idea to call pdflatex with an absolute path. Switch to the folder and then use `pdflatex myfile`.

Comment: the pdf file would be generated in the current directory of the pdflatex process launched from vba not from the folder with your tex file.

Comment: I solved the problem following your suggestions. I entered this VBA instruction: Shell "cmd.exe /c ""cd C:\temp\" & " && pdflatex mydocument.tex". Thank you so much!